# Finding Transformation Matrix from source/destination vector pairs dataset

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a color processing problem I'm trying to solve. When we convert RGB colors to different colorspaces, we use 3x3 matrices. For example if s is a source RGB color vector, M is a 3x3 colorspace transformation matrix, and d is the result RGB color vector, the equation would look like this:

M*s = d

My problem:

I have a dataset of source/destination RGB color pairs that come from a colorspace conversion and am trying to find a "best fit" transformation matrix. Basically I'm trying to reverse-engineer the colorspace conversion and figure out what 3x3 transformation matrix was used. How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is a linear transformation mapping $S$ to $D$, you can do one thing. Take three input vectors $S = [s_1, s_2, s_3]$ and corresponding output vectors $D = [d_1, d_2, d_3]$. Now you can easily use matrix algebra to get the transformation $M$,  you can do $M = DA^{-1}$.

If you take more than three vectors, you can use pseudo inverse of $A$, but for unique $3×3$ matrix estimation, having three vectors is enough.